# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] while uploading CSV

Tags: php, sql, csv, pdo, upload

I'm trying to Upload a CSV-File into a MySQL Database via the PHP PDO function. The CSV is uploaded by a html form and saved on the server. After this I do some validation (I have exclude this from the code below). However I was pretty sure it was functional and I uploaded several times successful a CSV-Files, but after a week it stopped working with the following error code:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General      error: 7890 Can't find file
```

This is the code im using:

```
$csv_upload_status = "none";
$sec_pass = "4220334";

$databasehost = "127.0.0.3"; 
$databasename = "database_name"; 
$databasetable = "table_name"; 
$databaseusername="database_user"; 
$databasepassword = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\r";


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$valid = 1;
$target_dir = "schedule-uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["csv"]["name"]);
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($valid == 1) {  

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

    $csvfile = basename( $_FILES["csv"]["name"]);


    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
            $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
            array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
    }

    $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
          FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
          LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)."
          (@date, show_time, show_title, show_plot)
          SET show_date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y');");

    $csv_upload_status = "success";

}

}
```

Comment: The file path needs to be the full path (not relative) and mysql must be able to access it.

Comment: I don't see how this could have worked: You move your uploaded file to a subdirectory and then you try to read the file using just the name `$csvfile`. `$pdo->quote($target_file)` probably solves your problem.